# Remove specific value in R or Linux

Tags: r, linux

Hi I have a file (tab sep) in terminal that has several columns as below. You can see last column has a comma in between followed by one or more characters.

1    100    Japan    Na    pa,cd

2    120    India    Ca    pa,ces

5    110    Japan    Ap    pa,cres

1    540    China    Sn    pa,cd

1    111    Nepal    Le    pa,b

I want to keep last column values before the comma so the file can look like

2    120    India    Ca    pa

5    110    Japan    Ap    pa

1    540    China    Sn    pa

1    111    Nepal    Le    pa

I have looked for sed but I cannot find a way to exclude them

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you can read the file with a tab-separator and remove the values after comma.

```
result <- transform(read.table('file1.txt', sep = '\t'), V5 = sub(',.*', '', V5))
```

`V5` is used assuming it is the 5th column that you want to change the value.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
df1 <- read.tsv('file1.txt', sep="\t")
df1$V5 <- sub("^([^,]+),.*", "\\1", df1$V5)
```